# Unique rounding up and down number with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a unique rounding up and down like the example below:

```
10100 rounded down to 10000
10200 rounded down to 10000
10250 rounded up to 10500
10300 rounded up to 10500
10750 rounded up to 11000
```

has anyone ever written in javascript algorithm?

Comment: there's no consistency to the rounding ... seems like it's the nearest 500  for the first 3, then the nearest 100 for the next 2 ... this can't be solved with an *algorithm* since there's no consistency - what does 10600 round to? what about 10100?

Comment: sorry I was wrong in writing the example of rounding, I just edited it, if 10600 will be rounded to 10500

Comment: so it's simple ... `Math.round(v /500) * 500`

Comment: as simple like that?

Comment: try it - though, it may only be 99.99999% accurate - floating point in javascript (in any language actually) is a harsh mistress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't concerned with the incredibly small chance your value is off due to floating-point precision, I would go with Jaromanda's answer.

With that said, if you would like to keep everything as integers, you can use the function below:

```
function round(n) {
    var difference = n % 500;
    if(difference > 249) n += 500;
    if(difference < -249) n -= 500;
    n -= difference;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is a better approach - though, does it work correctly with negative values?

Comment: @JaromandaX Ah good point, I'll edit it to allow negatives. Thanks.